# Firestore: Given a list of document ids, what's the cheapest and most elegant way to check which records actually exist?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of document ids, some of which could be deleted. I need to get a list of records that still exist. I use Firestore Web API. The operation must be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a separate doc with a list of ids. Update it on onCreate and onDelete with Firebase functions. Fetch it when you need the list. Could be efficient, depends on how often you create, delete docs.
You can also update it server side without cloud functions, or on a protected client route.

Comment: Due to the lack of better options, I did something close to this. Thanks. P.S. I upvoted this, but my votes don't count yet.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an efficient way to do this. You would have to read all documents and filter them client side to build the list you need, or you would have to check one query at a time.

Comment: Thanks. P.S. I upvoted this, but my votes don't count yet.